# create dynamic SQL with anorm

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, anorm

i do not want to delete and reinsert every row, so I have used the following to try to use multiple rows with anorm:

```
SQL("""
            delete from PERSON_ROLES 
            WHERE person_id = {userId}
            and role_id not in ({rolescommastring})
            )
            """).on('userId -> userId,
                    'rolescommastring -> rolescommastring).execute()
```

The above yields a string that it doesn't like and i get :

> `c.j.b.PreparedStatementHandle - delete from PERSON_ROLES
>   WHERE person_id = 1460
>   and
>   role_id not in ( '1, 3, 8, 9' )`

can i create dynamic sql with anorm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anorm doesn't support 'IN' clauses. It is same for most of the ORMs (like scala- slick) as prepared statements do not support IN clauses

The process that I use is from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/qls6dhhdayc/discussion

Basically something like this should work

```
val params = List(1, 3, 8, 9) 
val paramsList = for ( i <- 0 until params.size ) yield ("role_id" + i)

SQL("""
        delete from PERSON_ROLES 
        WHERE person_id = {userId}
        and   role_id not in ({%s})
        )
        """.format(paramsList.mkString("},{"))).on('userId -> userId ++ 
                paramsList.zip(params)).execute()
```

Comment: This might be ok for integers, but it should not be used as a general solution, as it is ripe for SQL injection.

Answer (score 4):

Since Anorm 2.3, multi-value parameters are supported.

```scala
SQL("""
        delete from PERSON_ROLES 
        WHERE person_id = {userId}
        and   role_id not in ({rolescommastring})
        )
        """).on('userId -> userId,
                'rolescommastring -> Seq("id1", "id2", "id3")).execute()
```

There are more similar examples at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaAnorm